# Handsontable afterChange event is triggered on rows that haven't been changed

Tags: handsontable

I have noticed that if I edit a row in a table containing a date the afterChanges event is triggered more than once, but it should only be triggered once because I have only added a row,

Answer (score 1):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLq3jktv/52/) with a simple `afterChanges` handler shows that each time you edit a date you get only one `afterChanges` event triggered.

Perhaps you are making changes to cell values inside your `afterChanges` event handler?

Calling `setDataAtCell` inside `afterChanges` will trigger another call to `afterChanges`. If you do - you need to check for `source !== 'afterChange'` inside you `afterChanges` event handler like [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4d596fh/).